# Simulating a fail using CCLocationManager

Tags: ios, location

I would like to simulate a fail while using the CCLocationManager. The code I use today is something like this.

First kick off the location update thingy.

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And if stuff fails

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [[ActivityIndicator sharedInstance] hide];
}
```

However, stuff never fails it seems and I would like to simulate a true error from the locationManager. The root of the problem is that I have a few users that say that the location search never finishes resulting in a block since the ActivityIndicator is in the way.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experieced the same long location measuring time on my ipod touch 4g.
Instead of trying to trigger didFailWithError in a manual way, try to use a NSTimer with 30s delay (should be fine, may be tuned to your needs) that calls stopupdatinglocation, hides your activity indicator and shows an error message to the user.